# Poweredge 2500 6C822 PDM Board Pinouts?

Tags: power-supply, power-management

Okay, here's a strange one: I am trying to use an old Poweredge 2500 chassis to house a newer ATX-type motherboard.

What I need to know is this:

1. What are the pinouts for the 6C822 Power Distribution Module?
2. Is it possible to control the original power supplies and 6C822 PDM using a standard ATX board? Is there a feasible workaround if not?

Why I am even considering this:

1. I want to have the redundancy of multiple power inputs and supplies.
2. I want to take advantage of the 2500's cooling.
3. I have essentially zero budget for buying a new or used machine already configured for what I want. I got the 2500 for free.
4. I like a ridiculous challenge.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with PE2500 chassis is that you won't be able to fit an ATX board inside. The mounting holes are different and location of expansion slot section in regards to IO area is different too (similar to BTX, but BTX won't fit either)

Older power supplies while being redundant do not fit the demands of modern CPUs/motherboards.  They provide most of power on 3.3/5V rails... while modern systems mostly use the 12V rail.

Well at least rebuilding this chassis to house a modern ATX board certainly fits the "ridiculous challenge" description.

Comment: I've already addressed the mounting problem by cutting off the old tabs and drilling new holes. I am using insulating standoffs to hold the board away from the chassis and avoid shorting the whole thing out. Interesting note about the supply currents, though. I'll have to check that out.

Comment: Comparing apples to oranges, each of the 2500's 3 supplies is 300W max. The old ATX supply is 450W max. Max values follow: +5V Dell=95W, ATX=140. +12V Dell=228W ATX=288. +3.3V Dell=60W ATX=59W. The Dell doesn't have a -5V rail. From what I understand, I shouldn't need it.